# Regarding Probability Estimates predicted by LIBSVM

Tags: svm, libsvm

I am attempting 3 class classification by using SVM classifier. How do we interpret the probabililty estimates predicted by LIBSVM. Is it based on perpendicular distance of the instance from the maximal margin hyperplane?.

Kindly through some light on the interpretation of probability estimates predicted by LIBSVM classifier. Parameters `C` and `gamma` are first tuned and then probability estimates are outputted by using `-b` option with both training and testing.

Answer (score 1):

Multiclass SVM is always decomposed into several binary classifiers (typically a set of one vs all classifiers). Any binary SVM classifier's decision function outputs a (signed) distance to the separating hyperplane. In short, an SVM maps the input domain to a one-dimensional real number (the decision value). The predicted label is determined by the sign of the decision value. The most common technique to obtain probabilistic output from SVM models is through so-called [Platt scaling (paper of LIBSVM authors)](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/plattprob.pdf).

> Is it based on perpendicular distance of the instance from the maximal margin hyperplane?

Yes. *Any* classifier that outputs such a one-dimensional real value can be post-processed to yield probabilities, by calibrating a logistic function on the decision values of the classifier. This is the exact same approach as in standard [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

Answer (score 0):

SVM performs binary classification. In order to achieve multiclass classification libsvm performs what it's called one vs all. What you get when you invoke `-b`is the probability related to this technique that you can found explained [here](http://courses.media.mit.edu/2006fall/mas622j/Projects/aisen-project/) .

Comment: Note that LIBSVM implements the “one-against-one” approach (Knerr et al., 1990) for multiclass classification