# Calculate probability MLLIB SVM multi-class

Tags: apache-spark, svm, probability, apache-spark-mllib

I would like to know how to calculate the probability using Spark MLLIB SVM in a multi-class classification problem.
The documentation shows there is no such function available.
[LibSVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802556/regarding-probability-estimates-predicted-by-libsvm) uses [Platt-scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platt_scaling).

My questions are:

1. Is there a function to calculate the probability somewhere?
2. If not, who can help me implementing such functionality?

I would simply take the average distances from all the support vectors for each category after training and compare the distance from a new data-point to hyperplanes from all the classifiers.
I think the [SVMModel.predict()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/ClassificationModel.html#predict%28org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD%29) gives these distances, but I am uncertain.

Comment: SVM's aren't suitable for calculating posterior class probabilities, since they are constructed only to find class boundaries. If you want probabilities, I think you should take another approach, e.g. neural network or a decision tree with output score = proportion of positive examples in leaf region.

Comment: @RobertDodier LibSVM does support it, as well as the scientific literature: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.1639 So I think calculating the posterior probability is possible, but it is not available in Spark MLLib. Since I do not get any response from the community regarding such functionality being already available, I conclude that I have to implement it myself?

Comment: The OP (What does OP stand for anyway?) is seeking posterior probabilities only as a means to an end.  His real goal is multiclass SVM.

Comment: OP = Original Poster

Comment: warming up this old question: has anyone a solution except for implementing the platt-scaling by oneself?

Comment: Maybe look into clustering techniques. Start with Kmeans or even simpler K-nearest neighbor. SVM works best for binary class problems.